# The application is not compatible with any of your devices, after publishing

Tags: android, google-play, android-manifest

just 6-8 hours ago, the application was published on the play market, the requirements of android 4.4 and higher. For some reason, on all devices, it says "The application is incompatible with your device."

Someone faced this, I do not know what could be wrong, for example, if a play service is needed, even if there is no advertising, maybe something with a manifest.

Comment: Have you used any library and yes then please list all?

Comment: show your manifest.

Answer (score 0):

i've used hardware.camera in manifest file, by default its required.

Now im changed it to android:required="false" and it fixed the problem